# java c3p0 OutOfMemoryError PermGen space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, space, c3p0, permgen

hi all i am face this problem. i am set PermGen space size is 512M
it is still OutOfMemoryError.
who can help me thanks.

```
Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2679)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0ImplUtils.supportsMethod(C3P0ImplUtils.java:309)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:104)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection    (WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:198)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
```

Comment: If you get PermGen OOM on `.getConnection()` you have a serious resource leak, which you should look for (or post the code for us to see), or you connection pool is waaaaay to large...

Comment: Do you use application container, `Tomcat` for example, or it is standalone application?